# Principle of conservation of mass and the shock speed

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, characteristics

Consider the Burgers equation $u_t+uu_x=0$ with the initial condition $$u_0(x) =
\begin{cases} 
u_l,x\leq0\\
u_r,x>0
\end{cases}$$
Consider the region in the $xt$−plane given by $[−1, X] × [0, T]$ where $X$ is big enough that the x−position of the shock is less than X when t = T. (You don’t need to worry about what $X$ is, just imagine that it’s really really big.) Argue, from the principle of conservation of mass, that if the shock moves at a constant speed, $s$, then $Q(t)=\int_a^budx$ satisﬁes
$Q(T) − Q(0) = sT(u_l − u_r ).$

**My attempt:**
We write the conservation law in the integral form over an arbitrary interval $[a,b]$
$$\int_a^b(\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}+\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}(\frac{u^2}{2}))dx=\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^budx+\frac{(u(b,t))^2}{2}-\frac{(u(a,t))^2}{2}=0$$ or denoting $Q(t)=\int_a^budx$ we get
$$\frac{d}{dt}Q(t)=\frac{(u(a,t))^2}{2}-\frac{(u(b,t))^2}{2}$$
Integrating over time $[0,T]$ we have
$Q(T) − Q(0)=\int_0^T(\frac{(u(a,t))^2}{2}-\frac{(u(b,t))^2}{2})dt$.

I am stuck here, how do I proceed next?

Comment: Note that $s=\frac{u_l+u_r}2$ and that the integrand is constant for $a,b$ large enuough.

Comment: @LutzL, can you clarify pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your assumptions, the shock-wave stays inside the interval over the selected time span. This means that $u(a,t)=u_l$ and $u(b,t)=u_r$ (see your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3159962/115115)). As the integrand in the last integral is thus constant, you get
$$
Q(T)−Q(0)=\frac{u_l^2-u_r^2}2T.
$$
Now by the Rankine-Hugoniot condition, the speed of the shock front in the mean of the left and right speeds, $s=\frac{u_l+u_r}2$. By the binomial formulas, the claim follows.