# Solving the Quasilinear PDE $u_{t} - u^2 u_{x} = 0$ with piecewise initial condition.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Solving the quaslinear PDE by the method of characteristics is a bit tricky for me.

I was trying to obtain the solution $u$ for the PDE

$$u_{t} - u^2 u_{x} = 0$$ 
The initial condition is given by:

$$u(x,0) = g(x) = \begin{cases} -0.5, & x \leq 0 \\ 1, & 0<x<1 \\ 0.5, & x \geq 1 \end{cases}$$

Using the method of characteristics I have tried to write the characteristic equation as

$$\frac{dt}{1} = \frac{dx}{-u^2}$$

Trying to obtain an expression for $u$ from the above equation seems tricky as there is no $u$ term.

Comment: The general solution is given implicitly: $u = f(x+u^2t)$. The actual tricky tricky part comes from applying the initial conditions.

Comment: Treat it as a constant.

Comment: @BAYMAX You may refer to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3159987/135643) on how to deal with discontinuities

Comment: [This similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3162688/135643) may also be of interest.

Comment: @Dylan Yes indeed, but nonconvex conservation laws (such as the present one - and not the linked posts) need a careful treatment.

Answer (score 5):

It is important to note that the flux $f(u)=-\frac13 u^3$ in the conservation law $u_t + f(u)_x = 0$ is nonconvex. The problem may be viewed as two neighbor [Riemann problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2539265/418542), for which one can compute the waves, and their potential interactions. A plot of the base characteristic lines in the $x$-$t$ plane is given below:

[image: characteristics]

One observes that the method of characteristics provides a unique solution $u = g(x + u^2 t)$ in some specific parts of the plane only. In facts, there may be zero, one or two characteristics passing at a given point $(x,t)$.
The previous plot suggest that a shock wave is generated at $x=0$, and that a rarefaction wave is generated at $x=1$. This claim is verified by convex hull constructions, a graphical method related to the Oleinik entropy condition for shock waves (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2539265/418542)):

[image: hull]

Here the Rankine-Hugoniot condition gives the shock speed $s = -\frac{1}{4}$. Hence, the following solution for times $t< \frac{4}{3}$ is obtained:
$$
u(x,t) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
&{-\tfrac12} & &\text{if}\quad x< {-\tfrac{1}{4} t}\\
&1 & &\text{if}\quad {-\tfrac{1}{4} t} < x \leq 1-t\\
&\sqrt{(1-x)/t} & &\text{if}\quad 1- t \leq x \leq 1-\tfrac14 t\\
&{\tfrac12} & &\text{if}\quad 1- \tfrac14 t \leq x
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
For larger times, the interaction between the shock and the rarefaction must be computed.